# How can I extract last years data based on today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, where-clause

I want to extract all the data from 2016 and usually I would use:

```
date > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

But when I run the report in January 2018, I still want it to show me 2016 data, and when I run it again in Feb 18, it then starts showing all of 2017 data.

Comment: "last year" is not 2016... try parameters instead.

Comment: Be *specific* about what the "window" of data you want to query is. And when a *transition* should occur. I.e. should it be that on January 31st at 11:55 you're seeing data for [`2016-01-01` - `2017-01-01`) and on February 1st at 00:05 you're seeing data for [`2017-01-01` - `2018-01-01`)? And what about in other months?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the year -2
  2018 - 2 = 2016

```
date > DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE())
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't work as the whole of 2018 will only show 2016, I want it to automatically change to show all of 2017 only from the 1st of Feb 2018 to 31st Jan 2019.

I don't want to have to keep changing it every year.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract `Month` instead of `Year` like below :

```
DATEADD(month, -13, GETDATE())
```